Application command's locale names for Python Discord Bot (multi-lingual alias name)
According to the users' language setting, how can I make the application command's name have different names
For example, if one user sets his language of discord as English, the user can see the name of the application command in English. For another one, if another user sets his discord language as French, then the users can see the name of the identical application command in French.
To do this, I tried to utilize app_commands.locale_str but it didn't work. I think that it's because the **kwarg are passed and stored at the parameter extras so it does not impact any translation. The following code says the code example that I tried.
@bot.tree.command(name=app_commands.locale_str(
        "hello",
        fr = 'bonjour',
    ), 
    guild=guild)
@app_commands.default_permissions(manage_channels = True)
async def hello(interaction: Interaction) -> None:
    await interaction.response.send_message(content='hello')

Please could anyone suggest methods to implement the command that I explained above? Or please let me know how to implement this if anyone know this method.

You're in the right path, you need to also create your own Translator class and handle all the translations there, example:
import discord
from discord import app_commands


@bot.tree.command(
    name=app_commands.locale_str("hello"), guild=guild
)
@app_commands.default_permissions(manage_channels = True)
async def hello(interaction: Interaction) -> None:
    await interaction.response.send_message(content='hello')


class MyTranslator(app_commands.Translator):
    async def translate(
        self, 
        string: app_commands.locale_str,
        locale: discord.Locale,
        context: app_commands.TranslationContext
    ) -> str | None:
    if context.name == "hello":  # check command name
        if locale is discord.Locale.french:  # check locale
            return "bonjour"
    return None

# set up your translator, e.g in setup_hook
async def setup_hook():
    await bot.tree.set_translator(MyTranslator())


bot.setup_hook = setup_hook

Also, remember to sync your commands so the translation works.
Reference:

app_commands.locale_str
app_commands.Translator
discord.Locale
Tree.set_translator
Bot.setup_hook


In Discord.py, locale strings simply are used to mark that a string is ready for translation. The actual job of translation is done by the translator that is assigned to the tree in which the command resides. You will need to create a class that extends the discord.app_commands.Translator class, and call await tree.set_translator(translator) (with translator being an object of your translator class). An example can be found here.
